# remove saved image while editing the form magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

**Before explaining what is my issue let me explain what I want to achieve?**

I am creating a custom form which takes some information and saves into a custom table.It includes a **file upload** which is mostly an image.

**So what I did?**

I successfully uploaded the file to a location on server and saved the information as well as file name on my custom table.Below is what i did to save the file.

```
<?php 


namespace Custom\Addprofile\Controller\Index;

//use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;
use Magento\Framework\Filesystem;
use Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\UploaderFactory;

class Addprofile extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action {

    protected $resultPageFactory;

     /**
     * @var RequestInterface
     */
    protected $request;
    protected $_objectManager;
    protected $messageManager;

    protected $uploaderFactory;

    protected $fileSystem;

    protected $fileId = 'concession_card';
    protected $allowedExtensions = ['jpg', 'png', 'jpeg'];

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request,
        \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager,
        \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface $messageManager,
        UploaderFactory $uploaderFactory,
        Filesystem $fileSystem
    ){
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;      
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->request = $request;
        $this->_objectManager = $objectManager;
        $this->messageManager = $messageManager;
        $this->uploaderFactory = $uploaderFactory;
        $this->fileSystem = $fileSystem;
    }
    public function execute(){
        $post = $this->request->getPostValue();
        if (isset($_FILES['concession_card']['name']) && $_FILES['concession_card']['name'] != "") {
                    $destinationPath = $this->getDestinationPath();

                    $uploader = $this->uploaderFactory->create(['fileId' => $this->fileId])
                    ->setAllowCreateFolders(true)
                    ->setAllowRenameFiles(true)
                    ->setAllowedExtensions($this->allowedExtensions);

                if (!$fileData = $uploader->save($destinationPath)) {
                    throw new LocalizedException(
                        __('File cannot be saved to path: $1', $destinationPath)
                    );
                }
                $fileName = $fileData['file'];
                $post['concession_card'] = $fileName;
                }
        //var_dump($post);die();
        $model = $this->_objectManager->create('Custom\Addprofile\Model\Profile');
        $model->setData($post);
        $model->save();
        $this->messageManager->addSuccess('Profile has been successfully added.');
    }

    public function getDestinationPath()
    {
        return $this->fileSystem
            ->getDirectoryWrite(DirectoryList::MEDIA)
            ->getAbsolutePath('/customer/profile/');
    }
}
```

Till here there is no issue.But let us assume if I need to edit the same form.I need to again take the image and replace it with the image. I can do all these using above code but I couldn't remove the previously uploaded image.

The reason I want to delete previously uploaded image is, there is no use of it so removing it would be a good idea.

**In short**

I want to remove the previously uploaded image and replace it with new one.

So can anyone help me out here. How can I remove the previously uploaded image in magento 2?

Thanks

Comment: in admin or frontend form?

Comment: I want to make it work in frontend

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are saving this data in your custom table, so let's assume you have `primary id` in your custom table like(`cid`)

In your form html you have to set `cid` in `hidden` variable like

```
<input type="hidden" name="cid" value='<?php echo $cid?>' >
```

Where `$cid` is primary id , I think you can easily get like other data.

Now in your `controller` `action`

```
$post = $this->request->getPostValue();
```

So in your controller you will get `cid` if your form is edit one , so lets first check if its saved one or edit one

`$cid=$post['cid'];`

```
if(!empty($cid)){
        $model = $this->_objectManager->create('Custom\Addprofile\Model\Profile')->load($cid);
        $previousImage=$model->getConcessionCard(); 
        if(file_exists($previousImage)){ // here we are checking Image is exist or not. If its exist then we can remove it
        unlink($previousImage);
        }
}
```

Comment: i think you are not getting me. I don't want to remove it from table, i can easily do it. My question is removing the image from real location where image is saved.like in catalog/media/image. I hope you get me now.

Comment: I think you are not getting my code.         unlink($previousImage); will remove the image from your real location. :)

Comment: ok sorry i may have misunderstood you.So if i do as above $previousImage variable gets only the name of the image is that sufficient to remove by using unlink function, don't we need the full path to image? How it will figure out the path?

Comment: If you are not saving the full path of Image then you have to append the getDestinationPath with the image name , I think it's damm simple. And accept the answer If you find it helpful :) @aton1004

Comment: Ok don't worry i will accept it once i fully test it. thanks for the help